# Bundle Chrome with particular extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, extension

I am currently responsible for the IT-security of a rather large group of people. A majority of our issues come through simple mistakes that could have been avoided with an integrated adblocker for Chrome.

They don't know how to install Chrome extensions and there are way to many of them for me to go door-to-door and do it for them. There is also a good chance most of them will just downright not bother doing it, even if the process of installing an adblocker is explained.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way I can bundle Chrome with a few hand-picked extensions (like and adblocker) which will essentially come "with" their Chrome installation?

Does such an option exist?

Comment: I'm not certain about the bundling.  Another option is to appoint "expert users" in each department, teach them, and have them do the AdBlock installation for their fellow users.  Depending on the size of your organization, intra-department trust between users, willingness of people to get the job done quickly rather than insist on it being "your job", etc etc, this may work for you.  Another option is to make a PDF with screenshots of each step, and announce that you'll go around in a week to make sure that people are "compliant".  It's just another way of getting people to protect themselves

Comment: @ChristopherHostage They can be "bundled". See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there is a way I can bundle Chrome with a few hand-picked extensions?

Yes. You use what is called an [External Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions):

> Sometimes you might want an extension to be installed via other means.
>   Here are two typical cases:
>
> - An extension is associated with some other software, and the extension should be installed whenever the user installs that other
>     software.
> - **A network admin wants to install the same extensions throughout their organization.**
>
> An extension that's installed neither from the Chrome Web Store nor as
>   an inline installation is known as an external extension. For
>   developers who want to distribute an extension as part of the
>   installation process for other software, or for network admins that
>   want to distribute an extension throughout their organization, Google
>   Chrome supports the following extension installation methods:
>
> - Using a preferences JSON file (for Mac OS X and Linux only)
> - Using the Windows registry (for Windows only)
>
> Both ways support installing an extension hosted at an update_URL. On
>   Windows and Mac, the update_URL must point to the Chrome Web Store
>   where the extension must be hosted.
>
> The preferences file on Linux can point to your own server where you
>   are hosting the extension (see autoupdating). The preferences JSON
>   file also supports installing an extension from a .crx extension file
>   on the user's Linux computer (see hosting).
>
> Install extensions from your website: Among these methods, the safest
>   option for your users is to publish your extension in the Chrome Web
>   Store. Instead of hosting your own extension, publish it in the store,
>   and provide an inline installation link from your website.

Source [Alternative Extension Distribution Options - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions)

The above link provides detailed instructions for Windows, MacOS and Linux (which are too long to reproduce here).

Comment: Now, I've only skimmed it, but the way I understand it, this would require a custom registry file to be implemented on every computer that I want to force my extension-of-choice on. Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @ViRALiC On Windows yes. But adding that registry entry is scriptable.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore since Chrome on Windows and Mac requires all extensions to be installed from Web Store.

Warning
Windows and Mac installs must come from Chrome Web Store: As of Chrome 33, no external installs are allowed from a path to a local .crx on Windows (see Protecting Windows users from malicious extensions). As of Chrome 44, no external installs are allowed from a path to a local .crx on Mac (see Continuing to protect Chrome users from malicious extensions).